# How to populate an array of C# structs in C++ via P/Invoke

Tags: c#, c++, struct, pinvoke

I'm using C++ to perform some calculations and return an array of populated data structs to C#. My research has led me to conclude the best way of doing this is to instance the structs in C# first, then send them to C++ to be populated. Please let me know if this not the best approach.

So I'm trying to populate an array of C# structs in C++ via P/Invoke call. I have successfully populated a single C# struct in C++, but am struggling with the array. Here is the C++ struct and logic for single and (attempted) multiple population:

```
struct Prediction
{
    int Combination[6] = {};
    double Value;
};

extern "C"
{

    ///<summary>Populate a pointer to a test prediction struct with data</summary>
    __declspec(dllexport) void PopulateTestPrediction(OUT Prediction* pPrediction)
    {
        (*pPrediction).Value = 42;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            (*pPrediction).Combination[i] = i;
        }
    }

    ///<summary>Populate a pointer to a test prediction struct with data</summary>
    __declspec(dllexport) void PopulateTestPredictions(OUT Prediction** pPredictions, int predictionCount)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < predictionCount; i++)
        {
            Prediction* pPrediction = pPredictions[i];
            (*pPrediction).Value = i;
            for (size_t j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                (*pPrediction).Combination[j] = j;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the C# code I'm using to call the C++:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;

namespace Estimator.Predictors
{

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Prediction
    {

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
        public int[] Combination;

        /// <summary></summary>
        public double Value;

    }

    public class PredictorManager
    {

        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        [DllImport("NativeEstimator.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern void  PopulateTestPrediction(ref Prediction prediction);

        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        [DllImport("NativeEstimator.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern void PopulateTestPredictions(ref Prediction[] predictions, int length);

        public static void TestPredictionPopulate()
        {
            var prediction = new Prediction {Combination = new int[6]};
            PopulateTestPrediction(ref prediction);
            Debug.WriteLine($"SizeOf: {Marshal.SizeOf(prediction)}");
            Debug.WriteLine($"Expected: {42.0}, Actual: {prediction.Value}");
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) Debug.WriteLine($"Expected: {i}, Actual: {prediction.Combination[i]}"); ;
        }

        public static void TestPredictionsPopulate()
        {
            const int PREDICTION_COUNT = 4;
            Prediction[] predictions = new Prediction[PREDICTION_COUNT];
            for (int j = 0; j < PREDICTION_COUNT; j++)
            {
                predictions[j].Combination = new int[6];
            }
            PopulateTestPredictions(ref predictions, PREDICTION_COUNT);
            for (int j = 0; j < PREDICTION_COUNT; j++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"SizeOf: {Marshal.SizeOf(predictions[j])}");
                Debug.WriteLine($"Expected: {42.0}, Actual: {predictions[j].Value}");
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) Debug.WriteLine($"Expected: {i}, Actual: {predictions[j].Combination[i]}"); ;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The single one works, but when I try to populate an array of structs, it fails. Could someone please advise where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Your C++ code doesn't work with an array of struct. It's an array of pointers to struct. Switch it to an array of struct and remove the `ref` from the C# array param.

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated. Following your advice, I treated the struct like a blittable type and just used the syntax:

`PopulateTestPredictions(Prediction* predictions, int predictionCount)`

And an indexer:

`Prediction prediction = predictions[i]`. This allowed me to read the struct array in C++ correctly, however when I modify it in C++, the modified values are not available in the structs back in C#. Have I missed a part of your explanation?